# Using different data in geom_rug than rest of plot for facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am producing a `geom_line` plot. I want to use `geom_rug` on the x-axis using different data than is used to create the `geom_line`. Details for how to do this can be found here: [Using different data in ggplot's geom_rug than I use in the rest of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159950/using-different-data-in-ggplots-geom-rug-than-i-use-in-the-rest-of-the-plot)

I want to do the same thing using `facet_grid` but cannot figure out how to make that work.

Here is my data for creating the `geom_line`:

```
data <- structure(list(id = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
"31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
"42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", 
"53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", 
"64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", 
"75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", 
"86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", 
"97", "98", "99", "100", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
"31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
"42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", 
"53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", 
"64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", 
"75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", 
"86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", 
"97", "98", "99", "100"), expl.name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("B.Al", "OA.P"), class = "factor"), 
    expl.val = c(166.0068, 210.159721212121, 254.312642424242, 
    298.465563636364, 342.618484848485, 386.771406060606, 430.924327272727, 
    475.077248484848, 519.23016969697, 563.383090909091, 607.536012121212, 
    651.688933333333, 695.841854545454, 739.994775757576, 784.147696969697, 
    828.300618181818, 872.453539393939, 916.606460606061, 960.759381818182, 
    1004.9123030303, 1049.06522424242, 1093.21814545455, 1137.37106666667, 
    1181.52398787879, 1225.67690909091, 1269.82983030303, 1313.98275151515, 
    1358.13567272727, 1402.28859393939, 1446.44151515151, 1490.59443636364, 
    1534.74735757576, 1578.90027878788, 1623.0532, 1667.20612121212, 
    1711.35904242424, 1755.51196363636, 1799.66488484848, 1843.81780606061, 
    1887.97072727273, 1932.12364848485, 1976.27656969697, 2020.42949090909, 
    2064.58241212121, 2108.73533333333, 2152.88825454545, 2197.04117575758, 
    2241.1940969697, 2285.34701818182, 2329.49993939394, 2373.65286060606, 
    2417.80578181818, 2461.9587030303, 2506.11162424242, 2550.26454545455, 
    2594.41746666667, 2638.57038787879, 2682.72330909091, 2726.87623030303, 
    2771.02915151515, 2815.18207272727, 2859.33499393939, 2903.48791515152, 
    2947.64083636364, 2991.79375757576, 3035.94667878788, 3080.0996, 
    3124.25252121212, 3168.40544242424, 3212.55836363636, 3256.71128484848, 
    3300.86420606061, 3345.01712727273, 3389.17004848485, 3433.32296969697, 
    3477.47589090909, 3521.62881212121, 3565.78173333333, 3609.93465454545, 
    3654.08757575758, 3698.2404969697, 3742.39341818182, 3786.54633939394, 
    3830.69926060606, 3874.85218181818, 3919.0051030303, 3963.15802424242, 
    4007.31094545455, 4051.46386666667, 4095.61678787879, 4139.76970909091, 
    4183.92263030303, 4228.07555151515, 4272.22847272727, 4316.38139393939, 
    4360.53431515151, 4404.68723636364, 4448.84015757576, 4492.99307878788, 
    4537.146, 4.1204, 7.9417, 11.763, 15.5843, 19.4056, 23.2269, 
    27.0482, 30.8695, 34.6908, 38.5121, 42.3334, 46.1547, 49.976, 
    53.7973, 57.6186, 61.4399, 65.2612, 69.0825, 72.9038, 76.7251, 
    80.5464, 84.3677, 88.189, 92.0103, 95.8316, 99.6529, 103.4742, 
    107.2955, 111.1168, 114.9381, 118.7594, 122.5807, 126.402, 
    130.2233, 134.0446, 137.8659, 141.6872, 145.5085, 149.3298, 
    153.1511, 156.9724, 160.7937, 164.615, 168.4363, 172.2576, 
    176.0789, 179.9002, 183.7215, 187.5428, 191.3641, 195.1854, 
    199.0067, 202.828, 206.6493, 210.4706, 214.2919, 218.1132, 
    221.9345, 225.7558, 229.5771, 233.3984, 237.2197, 241.041, 
    244.8623, 248.6836, 252.5049, 256.3262, 260.1475, 263.9688, 
    267.7901, 271.6114, 275.4327, 279.254, 283.0753, 286.8966, 
    290.7179, 294.5392, 298.3605, 302.1818, 306.0031, 309.8244, 
    313.6457, 317.467, 321.2883, 325.1096, 328.9309, 332.7522, 
    336.5735, 340.3948, 344.2161, 348.0374, 351.8587, 355.68, 
    359.5013, 363.3226, 367.1439, 370.9652, 374.7865, 378.6078, 
    382.4291), pred.name = c("ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData", 
    "ABIBAL_EMmeanByKAPPA_mergedAlgo_mergedRun_mergedData"), 
    pred.val = c(0.72717134278985, 0.725580651952754, 0.72524989591983, 
    0.6847896439747, 0.683364054232711, 0.679084738378107, 0.682050122398816, 
    0.682475156500698, 0.683282306342872, 0.690601336574028, 
    0.719080690723904, 0.728016857155582, 0.729766797890853, 
    0.736719403015855, 0.73780272310383, 0.736603440931246, 0.73331516735191, 
    0.742270920645638, 0.746491297266575, 0.746554712226476, 
    0.746188300048702, 0.742489274064938, 0.733355326072199, 
    0.730126643135452, 0.72153842457826, 0.713355121029801, 0.707195149983283, 
    0.709882438983902, 0.708141150488086, 0.699838996226351, 
    0.692354821150764, 0.694191056563535, 0.69455343970604, 0.692675231546755, 
    0.680210446866081, 0.667422329631271, 0.666930813407143, 
    0.672483893303893, 0.676725933064531, 0.675322625914494, 
    0.668808375754112, 0.668526057372743, 0.672128553114884, 
    0.672503316150442, 0.670818130355739, 0.654873263850729, 
    0.647457540313021, 0.644325201384311, 0.630098255322099, 
    0.629093736319349, 0.631956837664675, 0.634981892474124, 
    0.634717095125294, 0.633462619604262, 0.630025651197226, 
    0.618532965856636, 0.60833892510183, 0.598753838567254, 0.599854791332255, 
    0.610734014751831, 0.622011690534745, 0.631885079280574, 
    0.644526327506554, 0.649651244847683, 0.657293379211696, 
    0.661655019343924, 0.664884292292121, 0.665909650179375, 
    0.665759482601196, 0.666392786926542, 0.663701221037765, 
    0.665111879685147, 0.665133523190044, 0.667190283826372, 
    0.667255976748053, 0.664847417193921, 0.665815629488989, 
    0.665500832699494, 0.665560794077397, 0.665891835899177, 
    0.665796121523331, 0.666098716225378, 0.664563779727549, 
    0.664477290323156, 0.664791081351549, 0.664850971241221, 
    0.664360447670554, 0.661786418505279, 0.66189351388425, 0.662119627130145, 
    0.663157220382035, 0.663215479771206, 0.663028519349897, 
    0.663124314796688, 0.662908747404815, 0.663248125378813, 
    0.663008575164198, 0.662757700777816, 0.662495939706323, 
    0.662223725420099, 0.697401970862329, 0.697884252319493, 
    0.708608099309274, 0.718428039278132, 0.720081032547858, 
    0.703263942479544, 0.699129489215344, 0.680840284502425, 
    0.682329471534046, 0.663736980048985, 0.667936399440617, 
    0.670498231549698, 0.670250984180479, 0.667778891972127, 
    0.665808149723955, 0.672562938112754, 0.670694194442744, 
    0.668548418231383, 0.667318924516411, 0.67863000147129, 0.685835929010938, 
    0.698370016672864, 0.698219207302802, 0.696492039091626, 
    0.69672464141991, 0.693966280077269, 0.689987186281631, 0.699523041494931, 
    0.704716751737007, 0.701527480566443, 0.707374550927681, 
    0.705311775014747, 0.706724275402224, 0.704622032299592, 
    0.702182141512277, 0.701842303422302, 0.701782963745101, 
    0.701430063765314, 0.702070848540208, 0.701615161845951, 
    0.701359134152649, 0.701303021366389, 0.700828747462252, 
    0.700171265037134, 0.696927293210558, 0.692666643467139, 
    0.691677231447202, 0.690480622415616, 0.687296807949962, 
    0.687289183181501, 0.686715402435284, 0.685909237292854, 
    0.684637497893908, 0.68320281844842, 0.680085600977186, 0.673993444077351, 
    0.66277615753816, 0.66128714411618, 0.659310230282222, 0.635711148519987, 
    0.631186056847906, 0.614496375352921, 0.607799334774614, 
    0.60394502175948, 0.6018651938099, 0.598506644984342, 0.596931463871896, 
    0.595432211214576, 0.594985012609138, 0.59359043191754, 0.592238453426632, 
    0.591987497540272, 0.600449596430731, 0.599848121774635, 
    0.598625538616827, 0.597386767645648, 0.596182395066323, 
    0.594714054518536, 0.593607208358167, 0.59256173545032, 0.591515413178505, 
    0.590482334939192, 0.589242145485193, 0.5851748294937, 0.580858900684018, 
    0.579608505277304, 0.578689112373011, 0.577811018873763, 
    0.576955568969071, 0.576127826324727, 0.575353848191133, 
    0.574729811651318, 0.574590910770464, 0.575786586416766, 
    0.577902801872356, 0.578463857087765, 0.576961223012548, 
    0.57619653002874, 0.575304513269498, 0.5743111862353)), row.names = c(NA, 
-200L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have created the desired plot with `geom_line` and `facet_grid` here:

```
rp.gg.theme <- theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
                     axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5),
                     panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "gray70"),
                     strip.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "gray70"),
                     panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey90"),
                     legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "gray70"))


gg.rp <- ggplot(data, aes(x = expl.val, y = pred.val, lty = pred.name)) +
  geom_line() + ylab("prob of occ") + xlab("") + 
  rp.gg.theme + 
  facet_grid(~ expl.name, scales = 'free_x')
print(gg.rp)
```

Now, I want to use `geom_rug` and add this data:

```
rug <- structure(list(variable = c("B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", 
"OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P", "B.Al", "OA.P"), value = c(338.7306, 
31.5596, 166.0068, 49.5544, 2201.7276, 9.1454, 402.7939, 43.2044, 
1970.4786, 87.574, 521.4103, 11.4107, 865.3218, 218.7527, 895.7069, 
13.3783, 1220.0331, 21.6166, 1034.3638, 38.6943, 1336.0037, 42.8909, 
619.1833, 7.3967, 847.7625, 29.1084, 1903.6358, 123.3097, 1943.941, 
26.6542, 2627.8662, 48.9228, 234.3216, 14.6005, 2328.6244, 74.2417, 
2772.8982, 382.4291, 2338.4696, 75.1301, 1191.6364, 352.0618, 
1084.9239, 86.3068, 1866.9324, 87.5619, 2658.3258, 30.6219, 4056.0008, 
7.2224, 1833.6639, 196.3462, 1386.4161, 41.1832, 1279.7507, 72.1865, 
3172.6446, 13.637, 810.8588, 17.047, 1264.9346, 100.2394, 2702.0688, 
65.5194, 1927.2849, 58.186, 1177.9621, 9.8152, 2272.7198, 24.9286, 
1263.5172, 109.803, 1128.6822, 107.9631, 1422.9009, 54.1503, 
1145.2507, 100.0588, 1208.1623, 9.7653, 4537.146, 37.4114, 2795.528, 
20.8056, 2455.4469, 104.7645, 1574.1654, 292.0432, 2467.4275, 
17.3406, 2812.943, 258.705, 4104.0072, 138.0702, 2446.2176, 122.7064, 
3827.8227, 179.7492, 3016.0579, 119.4728, 2005.8641, 84.9147, 
2221.4552, 74.7768, 3854.2153, 119.3948, 3258.059, 77.205, 1389.009, 
65.1995, 2713.1086, 99.2801, 1193.9555, 12.9142, 1242.4894, 25.8397, 
1154.538, 37.3684, 1135.2095, 12.0162, 1956.0639, 121.7294, 1775.0104, 
12.2683, 1563.474, 77.8089, 2063.9372, 16.9807, 2176.54, 106.8911, 
3094.113, 153.0956, 1136.6186, 24.3589, 2299.0027, 48.4024, 1590.6173, 
116.5247, 1720.9035, 258.8437, 2580.3197, 105.802, 2230.014, 
71.9742, 2577.9445, 110.244, 1853.0107, 83.0696, 1407.3711, 19.7838, 
2577.3846, 33.418, 1617.7941, 63.5428, 1321.0499, 38.7855, 175.337, 
209.3731, 1438.1217, 28.2349, 3485.9304, 178.816, 1714.779, 29.7508, 
1448.8005, 100.5838, 1021.9553, 102.0866, 1033.3259, 82.8745, 
1784.3257, 103.8347, 1360.6404, 10.4334, 1917.4213, 10.5674, 
2085.9287, 212.5898, 1541.3794, 60.6096, 1156.1343, 64.0802, 
977.4394, 120.9979, 1458.8867, 9.5453, 2967.5291, 62.9818, 3220.0618, 
112.5657, 1971.8916, 54.9495, 1998.3989, 47.2262, 3039.0514, 
50.226, 2105.1342, 120.5505, 733.8704, 123.9846, 3493.6414, 19.7758, 
703.7449, 15.0943, 592.7199, 42.2592, 1556.1657, 94.3278, 1995.4834, 
4.1204, 912.5269, 61.0262, 1393.5598, 83.1514, 700.4702, 90.2574, 
911.6709, 112.9965, 1263.6378, 159.626, 1227.2942, 52.1509, 2689.8105, 
30.2266, 3447.389, 69.1737, 1907.8344, 30.6473, 1039.9392, 34.5634, 
2442.1374, 109.1126, 1494.5479, 6.6474, 636.0785, 58.0179, 937.9868, 
53.5612, 631.2616, 49.7509, 845.6879, 37.3058, 1527.3876, 65.8385, 
1180.5868, 16.9759, 523.8141, 167.3752, 3291.8722, 33.1888, 613.6226, 
10.3609, 1252.5563, 27.2012, 1176.3373, 16.4956, 1883.121, 26.7092, 
1804.9273, 32.5718, 3436.859, 35.8225, 2438.9272, 15.8066, 1550.1794, 
79.9302, 1554.2781, 15.688, 1672.0914, 68.8866, 1921.1335, 13.8587, 
2436.1087, 171.4659, 2353.5127, 29.6696, 2073.7077, 26.3829, 
2450.1142, 11.0334, 515.0045, 9.0092, 3743.2041, 15.702, 822.2245, 
45.3919, 735.8311, 40.3787, 1639.5679, 20.9798, 1318.6194, 37.0689, 
1199.7957, 117.8243, 1221.4336, 67.7935, 2916.0962, 118.392, 
2047.1784, 204.4831, 991.2386, 161.5095, 1744.686, 38.7734, 1469.1305, 
115.6036, 821.8457, 60.2369, 1002.8326, 71.6061, 2794.651, 91.2041, 
865.7266, 261.7528, 4369.9753, 71.7757)), row.names = c(NA, -316L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

How can I add this data as `geom_rug` into the `facet_grid`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the faceting to work when you are pulling data from two different data sources is that the variable you use to facet must be present in both data sets. You can just rename the variable so they are the same. For example

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = expl.val, y = pred.val, lty = pred.name)) +
  geom_line() + ylab("prob of occ") + xlab("") + 
  rp.gg.theme + 
  facet_grid(~ expl.name, scales = 'free_x') +
  geom_rug(aes(x=value), inherit.aes=FALSE, transform(rug, expl.name=variable))
```

[image]